# Moving subfloat captions vertically

Tags: vertical-alignment, captions, subfloats, subcaption, vertical

How can I move the subcaptions of the subfloat vertically? My subfigures have a lot of white space and there appears a long white space between the subfigures and the subcaptions. So, I want to move the subcaptions vertically and potentially on the subfigures. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize,captionskip=-0.01mm,farskip=0mm]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!t]
            \hspace*{-0.85cm}
            \centering 
            \captionsetup{oneside,margin={0.5cm,0cm}}
            \subfloat[]{\includegraphics [height = 34mm] {example-image-a}}
            \hfil
            \vspace{-1.5mm}
            
            \hspace*{-0.85cm}
            \subfloat[]{\includegraphics [height = 34mm] {example-image-b}}
            \hfil
            \vspace{-1.5mm}
            
            \hspace*{-0.85cm}
            \subfloat[]{\includegraphics [height = 34mm] {example-image-c}}
            \hfil
            \vspace{-1.5mm}
            
            \hspace*{-0.85cm}
            \subfloat[]{\includegraphics [height = 34mm] {example-image-d}}
            \hfil
            \vspace{-1.5mm}
            
            \hspace*{-0.85cm}
            \subfloat[]{\includegraphics [height = 34mm] {example-image-e}}
            \vspace{3mm}
            
            \caption{Caption.}\vspace{-3mm}
            \label{label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which includes all required packages and gives the output you get if compiled.

Comment: Hi Imran. Is there anything missing in the above MWE?

Comment: You need to add at least the packages necessary like `caption`, `subcaption`, etc and demo images to make the code compile without any modification.

Comment: Something missing?, yes. Which package do you use for `\subfloat` command? Package `graphicx` is not loaded. And we don't have `image_...` files. It's better that you use images provided by `mwe` package.

Comment: I added the packages that sounded relative. Please let me know what else should be added.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the position of the `subcaption` using `captionskip`. A negative value will overlay it on the subfigure.

Use `farskip` to add some vertical space between the subfigures.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize,captionskip=-8mm,farskip=5mm]{subfig} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering 
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics [height = 34mm] {example-image-a}}     
        \hfil
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics [height = 34mm] {example-image-b}}
        \hfil
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics [height = 34mm] {example-image-c}}
        \hfil
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics [height = 34mm] {example-image-a}}
        \hfil
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics [height = 34mm] {example-image-b}}     
        \caption{Caption.}
        \label{label1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

`\hfil` fills all the horizontal space between adjacent subfigures. No need to use `\hspace{}`.